# Encoding json using poison with unicode

Tags: elixir, elixir-poison

I'm using `HTTPoison` to get the elixir guide website and then parsing it with `Floki` to build a HTML 2 Jupyter Notebook transformer (with Markdown for the description). I have to put in the ` backtick. `\u0060` for code highlighting, which works so far. I have some places where I use string Interpolation `"#{Floki.text(childs_nodes)}"` and in other Places `Enum.join ""` to process and transform from HTML to Markdown.

The transformed result is stored in a map according to the jupyter notebookformat. When I call `Poison.encode notebook` I get an error, as the codepoints are gone. I tried different things, but don't know yet, where the issue is.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong when processing the text? This is the exception:

```
** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {:source, ["Elixir also    provides `Port`, `Reference` and `PID` as data types (usually used in process communication), and we will take a quick look at them when talking about processes. For now, let’s take a look at some of the basic operators that go with our basic types."]}
lib/poison/encoder.ex:377: Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
lib/poison/encoder.ex:255: anonymous fn/3 in Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
lib/poison/encoder.ex:256: Poison.Encoder.List."-encode/3-lists^foldr/2-1-"/3
lib/poison/encoder.ex:256: Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
lib/poison.ex:41: Poison.encode!/2
(guide2nb) lib/cli.ex:27: CLI.process/1
(elixir) lib/kernel/cli.ex:76: anonymous fn/3 in Kernel.CLI.exec_fun/2
```

Comment: The value you are trying to encode doesn't look like a map, but a tuple. Paste your original value here (and/or the code that is trying to encode it)

Comment: Poison does not encode tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem here is that you are trying to encode a `Tuple`, while Poison only works with Maps and Lists.** If the value you were trying to encode was a Map instead of a tuple, it would work perfectly. Unicode has nothing to do with this.

```
iex(1)> value = %{source: ["Elixir also    provides `Port`, `Reference` and `PID` as data types (usually used in process communication), and we will take a quick look at them when talking about processes. For now, let’s take a look at some of the basic operators that go with our basic types."]}
iex(2)> Poison.encode(value)
{:ok,
 "{\"source\":[\"Elixir also    provides `Port`, `Reference` and `PID` as data types (usually used in process communication), and we will take a quick look at them when talking about processes. For now, let’s take a look at some of the basic operators that go with our basic types.\"]}"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint ... Going to refactor my code. Actually I'm only using maps and lists, but I have some flat_maps in the recursion of parsing the HTML tree. So some of my maps `%{cell_type: :code, metadata: %{}, source: ["0o777"]},` get converted to keyword lists with tuples. `[{:cell_type, :markdown}, {:metadata, %{}}, {:source, ["# Basic types"]},  {:cell_type, :markdown}, {:metadata, %{}}, {:source, []},`

Comment: It could be useful to change the name of the question to closer represent what the issue was. It would make it an easier reference for others.